# What is the definition of transversality used in this context?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, transversality

Now, I've been reading **V.I. Arnol'd, Characteristic Class Entering in Quantization Conditions** and I'm stuck on page 10. Here is the [link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5e3a/e0ef814a6a46733015a6678bb52409eb813a.pdf)

He tolds that

> $uM^{(n)}$ is such that its tangential mapping $\tau$ is transversal to every $\Lambda^k(n) \hookrightarrow \Lambda(n), k=1,2,\dots$.

However, I think the dimension of $\tau^* T_x (uM^{(n)}) + T_{\tau(x)} \Lambda^k(n)$ is strictly less than $T_{\tau(x)} \Lambda(n)$ for some large $k$.

How do I interpret this statement correctly?

**EDIT:** In here, $uM^{(n)}$ is an $n$-dimensional Lagrangian manifold.
$\Lambda(n)$ is an algebraic variety, called Lagrangian grassmanian, which is a collection of all Lagrangian subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.
$\Lambda^k(n)$ is a manifold of Lagrangian subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ whose intersection with standard position subspace($q=0$) is $k$-dimensional and it is $\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}$ codimensional submanifold of $\Lambda(n)$.
$\tau$ is a tagential mapping from $M^{(n)}$ to $\Lambda(n)$; mapping a point $x$ to the tangent space $T_xM$ of $M$ at the point, and it is well-defined since $M$ is a Lagrangian manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

The context is, he tried to assert that $uM^{(n)}$ is in general position from showing that each element of $\tau(uM^{(n)})$ is transverse to $\overline{\Lambda^1(n)}$.

Comment: Questions with intricate undefined notation don't do very well on this site. If you want to give your question a better chance of attracting an answer, you should (at the least) explain the question better.

Comment: @LeeMosher I got it. I've added some details a little bit now, and I will elaborate the question more later.